# ngx-permissions error with directive *ngxPermissionsOnly

Tags: angular5

I have a problem with the directive of the library ngx-permissions.
These are the versions of my angular's dependency:

```
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.3",
```

And I am following [this example](https://github.com/AlexKhymenko/ngx-permissions#individual-roles).

I am using the version of module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { NgxPermissionsModule } from 'ngx-permissions';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,

    // Specify your library as an import
     NgxPermissionsModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I can use the services without problem, but I have an error only with the directive.
The error is the next:

```
Can't bind to 'ngxPermissionsOnly' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
    </div>
            </div>
                <div [ERROR ->]*ngxPermissionsOnly="['ADMIN', 'GUEST']" class="m-portlet__head-tools">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pil"): ng:///DashboardModule/DashboardComponent.html@35:10
Property binding ngxPermissionsOnly not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("
                    </div>
                </div>
                [ERROR ->]<div *ngxPermissionsOnly="['ADMIN', 'GUEST']" class="m-portlet__head-tools">
                    <ul class="nav na"): ng:///DashboardModule/DashboardComponent.html@35:5
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue and my fix was to add **NgxPermissionsModule** for child module.

```
NgxPermissionsModule.forChild()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to say that I was also facing same issue. but in my case; I had a shared module and I did same as wiki says but solutions was just exports NgxPermissionsModule.

My issue went out and code is working fine.Check if you might have same case and my fix works for you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was using the latest version of NgxPermissionModule on a old angular version. Ensure that the

Comment: Ensure that the... what?

Answer (score 0):

**For Standalone Component**

**add NgxPermissionsModule.forRoot() to app.config.ts**

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [importProvidersFrom(NgxPermissionsModule.forRoot())]
};
```

**add NgxPermissionsModule in imports of the component**

```
imports: [NgxPermissionsModule],
```

**use ngxPermissionsOnly in html file**

```
<div  *ngxPermissionsOnly = "[ActionTypeEnum.APPROVE]">
      <h1>OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK</h1>
</div>
```